# How to enforce App Check to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I have implemented Cloud Functions, Firestore, Storage and Realtime Database in my project. The first three are in the same region(southamerica-east1), but Realtime Database had to be in us-central1.

Already followed all the steps to enforce App Check and it is working for Cloud Functions, Firestore and Storage, but in the AppCheck console the message for RTDB is "Start using Realtime Database to enable App Check".

Already made multiple queries to RTDB but there is no "Enforced" flag in App Check console for RTDB.

How can I properly enforce App Check for RTDB ?

Comment: I have the same issue, I only see "Start using Realtime Database to enable App Check" but have already been making both read and write requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AppCheck REST API:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/appcheck/rest/v1/projects.services/patch

[image: screenshot of appcheck config]

You can both Enforce and Unenforce using this API.

After doing this, the AppCheck metrics do not show in the firebase console immediately, they take a while to start showing up, however AppCheck tokens are verified / required as soon as enforcement is turned on.